# How can I rewrite an url and pass the full request url as parameter?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite an URL like `http://www.domain.tld/test/page.html?id=1&required=1&foo=bar`
to `http://www.domain.tld/wrapper.php?url=[FULL REQUEST URL]`

in wrapper.php I want `$_GET['url']` to be `http://www.domain.tld/test/page.html?id=1&required=1&foo=bar`

What I've tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*required=.*)$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /wrapper.php?url=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

But unfortunately `$_GET['url']` is now just `http://www.domain.tld/test/page.html?id=1` with the other parameters missing.

How should the correct apache synthax for this look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding QSA to the Rewrite rule

[L,QSA]

Comment: With this all variables are inside $_GET but $_GET['url'] contains the same like before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rule like this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)required=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule !^wrapper\.php /wrapper.php/http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}@%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/wrapper\.php)/([^@]*)@(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1?url=%2\?%3 [L,B]
```

Comment: rewrite to wrapper.php doesn't work at all with this :-/

Comment: It works perfectly fine in my testing. Make sure to test these rules independently first and add other rule later on.

Comment: ok rewrite works, but `echo $_GET['url'];` in wrapper.php now displays nothing.

Comment: Weird, for me `$_GET['url']` is showing full URL with query parameter.

Comment: I have made some changes in the rule, can you try updated rules now.

Comment: with this in root .htaccess I get 404 for `http://www.domain.tld/test/page.html?id=1&required=1&foo=bar`. With it in `/test/.htaccess` I still get an empty $_GET-Array

Comment: This was tested from root .htaccess only. Make sure when you test this with a root URL like first like: `http://www.domain.tld/page.html?id=1&required=1&foo=bar` (without `/test/) Also I believe `wrapper.php` is also in `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: Most likely you have `.htaccess` present both in `DocumentRoot` and in `/test/`.

Comment: Nope, I used `mv`, not `cp`.

Comment: Did you try: `http://www.domain.tld/page.html?id=1&required=1&foo=bar`? Is `wrapper.php` present as `http://www.domain.tld/wrapper.php`?